# How to set a button with a text in android

Tags: android, arrays, button, text

I have a question. Is it possible to make a button that has 3 lines of text. Here is my idea

```
|---------------|
|text1...       |
|text2...       |
|text3...       |
|_______________|
```

But the text I want to put on the button is received from an array and it changes dynamically. is this doable or there is an alternative that is easier to do?

Answer (score 4):

create the new line using "\n" in the button text

```
<Button 
        android:text="text1\ntext2\ntext3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

here it look like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to add a new line in a layout XML file:

Use `&#10;` (new line)

```
android:text="Hi&#10;Hello"
```

If you're trying to add a new line in code, just use '\n', same as in any other text.

If you can't see the second line, it may be that your Button doesn't have enough height. IE, in my case, the layout containing the button had a fixed height that just happened to make my button perfectly display one line of text.

**2nd method:**

1) Define in ../res/values/strings.xml:

```
<string name="multilines">Line1Line1\nLine2Line2</string>
```

2) Refer it in the layout file:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_multilines"
    android:text="@string/multilines"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
</Button>
```

**Dynamically:**

```
button.setText("Line1\nLine2\nline3");  //button is the Button of id "btn_multilines"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your text on button programatically like this :

```
btn.setText("Text1\n"+"Text2\n"+"Text3");
```

or you can set directly in xml like this :

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text1\nText2\nText3"/>
```